# Populate settings file using properties in view model or xaml c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a view model that has 50 properties. I would like to set up these properties in a .settings file so as to store the user inputs and reload them on startup of the project. I understand that I need to type these properties into the .settings file designer but since I already designed the xaml and typed up the get and sets of the properties in the view model, I was hoping not to have to manually re-type all 50 of the properties into the .settings file. Is there a way to use the view model or xaml to get these properties into the settings file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could serialize the view model to JSON and store *that* in your settings file as one setting instead of each of the properties of the view model